# Array list of File Objects getname to null String issue

Tags: java, string, null

Inside a java.awt.event.ActionEvent which may or may not be relevant.

```
List<File> files = new ArrayList<>() // File objects added earlier
String paths = null;
    for (File file : files){
        if (file.isFile()) {
            paths += file.getName() + "\n"; 
        }
    }

    taTemp.setText(paths);
```

The output is : 
null.stash
filename.txt
filtname2.txt

If we change String paths = "";

The output to
.stash
filename.txt
filename2.txt

Why does the first output add the "null"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default value of String is `null`, when printed it literally prints `null`. When you change it to `""` (empty string) that's what will be printed, as you can see from your testing results.

When you're appending to a String that's `null` it will just paste the text `stash` after `null` like `null.stash`.